# Add to cart button missing on porto

Tags: wordpress

I have a theme that I downloading but I don't have the activation key for it to update, can someone help me add an "add to cart" button please it disappeared and not showing, nor the price.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So the "add to car button" and the "price" disappeared from my Porto theme. It's currently running 6.2.5 but I don't know why the price isn't showing nor the add to cart on the product page.

Website: zarafex.com